# SQL to Update a column based on another table that isn't directly related

Tags: mysql

I'm working in moodle our badges aren't issued on the correct date due to the full years registers getting marked in one go at the end of the year.

The date of the course is the `mdl_facetoface_sesion_dates.timestart` 
The Badge Date is `mdl_badgeissued.dateissued`

I've tried various versions and below seems to be the closest I've got.

I'm currently working in phpmyadmin.

```
UPDATE
    mdl_badge_issued
SET
     mdl_badgeissued.dateissued = mdl_facetoface_sesion_dates.timestart
FROM mdl_badge_issued
INNER JOIN mdl_badge_issued.userid ON mdl_badge_issued.userid = mdl_user.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_badge ON mdl_badge_issued.badgeid = mdl_badge.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_course ON cmdl_course.id = mdl_badge.courseid 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface ON mdl_facetoface.course = mdl_course.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions ON mdl_facetoface_sessions.facetoface = mdl_facetoface.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates ON mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates.sessionid = mdl_facetoface_sessions.id

WHERE mdl_badgeissued.badgeid='62'
```

I would like to copy `mdl_badgeissued.dateissued = mdl_facetoface_sesion_dates.timestart`

Comment: And what is the problem with your query?

Comment: The error is   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM mdl_badge_issued
INNER JOIN mdl_badge_issued.userid ON mdl_badge_issued.us' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in this way: (your syntax was wrong)

```
UPDATE mdl_badge_issued
INNER JOIN mdl_badge_issued.userid ON mdl_badge_issued.userid = mdl_user.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_badge ON mdl_badge_issued.badgeid = mdl_badge.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_course ON cmdl_course.id = mdl_badge.courseid 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface ON mdl_facetoface.course = mdl_course.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions ON mdl_facetoface_sessions.facetoface = mdl_facetoface.id 
INNER JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates ON mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates.sessionid = mdl_facetoface_sessions.id
SET mdl_badgeissued.dateissued = mdl_facetoface_sesion_dates.timestart
WHERE mdl_badgeissued.badgeid='62'
```

Comment: Thanks.. new error  #1142 - SELECT command denied to user 'cpses_tovqigi1el'@'localhost' for table 'userid'

Comment: this is a permission issue. Issue is not related with your SQL.

Comment: I can update one user at a time with the following using the same logon UPDATE `mdl_badge_issued` SET `dateissued` = '1526653800' WHERE `mdl_badge_issued`.userid` = *userid*; but this means I need to search for each user in the user table to get their id first

Comment: one of your table does not have permission for select using your currenct user

Comment: I'm so glad I made a backup.. I've just changed 1000's of badges by accident.  I'll have a look at using another table to get the user ids. Cheers

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider to upvote and/or mark it as answer

Comment: The story so far. Whatever session id I use it makes all badges that date. 







UPDATE mdl_badge_issued bi 

JOIN mdl_user u ON bi.userid = u.id AND u.deleted = 0 

JOIN mdl_facetoface_signups ffs ON u.id = bi.userid 

JOIN mdl_badge b ON bi.badgeid = b.id 

JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = b.courseid 

JOIN mdl_facetoface f ON f.course = c.id 

JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions fs ON fs.facetoface = f.id 

JOIN mdl_facetoface_sessions_dates fsd ON fsd.sessionid = fs.id 





SET bi.dateissued = fsd.timestart 



WHERE bi.badgeid = 72

AND fs.id = 39

Comment: I've tried  WHERE bi.badgeid = 72 AND fs.id = 39 AND fs.id <> 6. it makes sessions 6 and 39 the same date as session 39 (and all other seesions).  hope this makes sense..

Comment: you need to open another question for this. Your problem is not same with your initial question. But please keep in mind that It is motivating for us to get upvote, and it is beneficial for the community to see marked answers so that others can benefit from this answer as well. It is mutual benefit scenario, we help you, you help us. This is how SO community works. thank you